# Можно ли не преобразовывать число в infinity? Или как сделать тест простоты Ферма на JS

Tags: javascript

Есть тест простоты Ферма. Написал такую функцию.
Однако с 17, получаю любое простое число - не простым. Обнаружил, что дело в том, что js преобразует большие числа в infinity, а затем при делении по модулю получаю NaN, потому алгоритм не работает. Можно как-то это исправить?

```js
    let checkingTheNumberForSimplicity = (number, amountTest = 100) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < amountTest; ++i) {
            let n = Math.round(Math.random() * (number - 2)) + 1;
            if ((n ** (number - 1)) % number !== 1) {
                console.log((n ** (number - 1)));
                console.log(n, i, (n ** (number - 1)) % number);
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    };
    console.log(2, checkingTheNumberForSimplicity(2)); 
    console.log(20, checkingTheNumberForSimplicity(20)); 
    console.log(7, checkingTheNumberForSimplicity(7));
    console.log(419, checkingTheNumberForSimplicity(419));
    console.log(1123, checkingTheNumberForSimplicity(1123));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Максимальное целое число, которое можно безопасно использовать в `JavaScript` `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER = 9007199254740991`.

Но исправить алгоритм нахождения простого числа можно, если использовать `Math.sqrt(n)`, т.к. искать делители числа имеет смысл только пока делитель меньше корня этого числа, иначе далее делители будут повторяться.

```js
function test(n) {
   if (isNaN(n) || !isFinite(n) || n%1 || n<2) return null; 
   var m=Math.sqrt(n);
   for (var i=2;i<=m;i++) if (n%i==0) return false;
   return true;
}

var numberphile = prompt("Ведите число", "17");
if (numberphile != null) {
  if (test(numberphile)==true) {
    alert( numberphile + ' — простое число');
    console.log(numberphile, '— простое число');
  } else if (test(numberphile)==false){
    alert( numberphile + ' — составное число');
    console.log(numberphile, '— составное число');
  }
}
```

Comment: Это, конечно, хорошее решение, но, к сожалению, это не совсем ответ.
По большому счету, мне надо, чтобы алгоритм был построен на малой теореме Ферма. Потому что этот алгоритм позволит независимо от величины числа найти ответ с одинаковой скоростью, практический. Здесь же с увеличением числа, будет и увеличиваться время выполнения, что очень нежелательно. Получается, что в js, не получится использовать алгоритм на основе малой теоремы Ферма?

Comment: @Igor, получится. если использовать библиотеки для работы с длинными числами